# Django model for books

Tags: python, django

I want to define a class for books.

- A book consists of several chapters.
- A chapter consists of several sections.
- A section consists of several subsections.

Is it okay to do it as follows?

```
class Book(models.Model):
  pass

class Chapter(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Section(models.Model):
  chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SubSection(models.Model):
  section = models.ForeignKey('Section', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  content = models.TextField()
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: A many-to-many means that a `Chapter` can belong to *many* books as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard way to do it, as it maps the corresponding SQL closely.

- In `Chapter` you define `book` as a foreign key
- `Book` class will *automatically* get a variable called `chapter_set`, which contains a list of chapter

This alone proves that you are doing it correctly. See *related managers* for more information

Same for subchapter